# How to update a datatable after submitting a dialog - JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

after so many search I couldn't find a way to update my datatable after a command button clicked in a primeface's dialog.

My mainMenu.xhtml has a datatable like:

```
<section id="ownermanagement">

<h:form id="ownermanagementform">
    <p:commandButton class="btn icon-cart" actionListener="#{ownerControl.viewNewOwnerDialog()}" value="کارفرما جدید"/>
    <br></br><br></br>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>
    <p:dataTable filterEvent="enter" id="ownerdatatable" value="#{ownerControl.ownerList}" var="owners" dir="rtl" emptyMessage="موردی با این مشخصات یافت نشد." style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <p:column filterBy="#{owners.id}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="header">شناسه</f:facet>
                #{owners.id}
        </p:column>
        <p:column filterBy="#{owners.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="header">نام</f:facet>
                #{owners.name}
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">عملیات</f:facet>
            <p:commandButton value="ویرایش کارفرما"
                             actionListener="#{ownerControl.viewEditOwnerDialog(owners)}" update="ownerdatatable"/> |
            <p:commandButton value="حذف کارفرما"
                             action="#{ownerControl.removeOwner(owners)}"
                             onclick="return confirm('آیا از حذف کارفرما اطمینان دارید؟')"
                             update="ownerdatatable"/> 
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
</section>
```

I open my dialog like this:

```
<p:commandButton class="btn icon-cart" actionListener="#{ownerControl.viewNewOwnerDialog()}" value="کارفرما جدید"/>
```

The viewNewOwnerDialog method is:

```
public void viewNewOwnerDialog() {
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("resizable", false);
    resetInputs();
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("createOwner", options, null);
}
```

This will open my createOwner page in a dialog:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>کارفرما جدید</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/style/elements.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body dir="rtl">
        <h:form id="newOwnerForm">
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true"/>
            نام: <h:inputText class="InputField" value="#{ownerControl.owner.name}"/>
            <br></br><br></br>
            توضیحات: <p:inputTextarea class="textArea" value="#{ownerControl.owner.description}" rows="5" cols="100" counter="display" maxlength="500" counterTemplate="{0}" autoResize="false" />
            <h:outputText id="display" /><br></br>
            <p:commandButton class="btn icon-cart" value="ثبت" action="#{ownerControl.insertOwner()}"  process="@all"  update=":ownermanagementform:ownerdatatable"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

How can I update a growl to show a message and after that I update the mainMenu's datatable?

At the moment, I get this error:

```
Cannot find component with expression ":ownermanagementform:ownerdatatable" referenced from "newOwnerForm:j_idt10".
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to add the id of the section to see if it's the problem ?!?

Comment: @Yagami Light yes, I've try that too. Still couldn't find my Component.

Comment: try to add a `widgetvar` to your datatable

Comment: @YagamiLight sorry dude, but still the same error

Comment: change the place of the growl make it before the form and update it

Comment: @YagamiLight I even removed the growl, but Still, i get the error. Growl is my second problem, i need to update the table at the first place!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125270/discussion-between-hamid-and-yagami-light).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Open Dialog" actionListener"...">
   <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="datatableID"/>
</p:commandButton>
```